# remove some object properties from the httpresponsemessage

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net, httpresponse

I have a class called CatalogSourceCodeItemsResponse  . This is how it is defined:

```
public partial class CatalogSourceCodeItemsResponse  
 {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private MMS.LoyaltyNext.API.SpendCard.MARSCatalog.CatalogFeed[] catalogFeedField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private string endDateField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private string sourceCodeField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private string startDateField;
}
```

**Note** I cannot modify/update the class as it is coming from a service.

I have created a web api which makes a request to a service and returns this class as the response. My requirement is that instead of returning all the properties, I need only the first one.

This is the code which returns the response:

```
[HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetCatalogItems()
        {
            CatalogSourceCodeItemsResponse response = new CatalogSourceCodeItemsResponse();
            response = //logic to return the response from the service
            return Request.CreateResponse<CatalogSourceCodeItemsResponse>(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
        }
```

The current output is

```
{
    "catalogFeed" : null,
    "endDate" : null,
    "sourceCode" : null,
    "startDate" : null
}
```

Required output is

```
{
    "catalogFeed" : null
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Create a new class with only the field(s) you want in the response and return that rather than the CatalogSourceCodeItemsResponse.

Comment: yes this is called a viewmodel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a ViewModel.

*A view model represents only the data that you want to display on your view/page, whether it be used for static text or for input values (like textboxes and dropdowns).*

```
 public partial class CatalogSourceCodeItemsResponse  
 {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private MMS.LoyaltyNext.API.SpendCard.MARSCatalog.CatalogFeed[] catalogFeedField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private string endDateField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private string sourceCodeField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private string startDateField;
}
```

View models differ from domain models in that view models only contain the data (represented by properties) that you want to use on your view. For example, lets say that you want to show only one item  in your CatalogSourceCodeItemsResponse  record, your view model might look like this:

```
public class CatalogSourceCodeItemsResponseViewModel
{
     private MMS.LoyaltyNext.API.SpendCard.MARSCatalog.CatalogFeed[] catalogFeedField; { get; set; }

}
```

Then your controller action will turn into

```
    [HttpGet]
            public HttpResponseMessage GetCatalogItems()
            {
                CatalogSourceCodeItemsResponse response = new CatalogSourceCodeItemsResponse();
                response = //logic to return the response from the service
                CatalogSourceCodeItemsResponseViewModel responseViewModel=new CatalogSourceCodeItemsResponseViewModel();
                responseViewModel.catalogFeedField=response.catalogFeedField;

                 return Request.CreateResponse<CatalogSourceCodeItemsResponseViewModel>(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseViewModel);
            }
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to expose service data contracts/db entities. For example, imagine what happens if you change these classes so that they contain some sort of sensitive data and you forget to update the way you expose these. It is always the best and cleanest option to define separate classes for public data. If you really want to get rid of extra source files and you can foresee that you are only going to use some data at 1-2 places, then you can opt to use anonymous types. So not even as an embedded property should you expose your business details, even duplication is better than that.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This solved my problem. However taking into consideration the concerns mentioned by @Balazs, I am going ahead with creating a separate class.

Comment: True,this is an introduction to the solution, maybe you should add more  as @balazs says